# Why filename autocompletion do not work?

Tags: bash, perl, autocomplete

When I type command:

`$ perl -Ilib t/mojolicious/patt`<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Autocompletion works fine. But when I use `-d` option:

`$ perl -Ilib -d t/mojolicious/patt`<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

It does not work. Why? How can I fix this?

**UPD** from comments

```
$ complete -p perl
bash: complete: perl: no completion specification

$ complete -D -p
complete -F _completion_loader -D

$ type _perl
bash: type: _perl: not found

$ type _completion_loader
_completion_loader is a function
_completion_loader () 
{ 
    local compfile=./completions;
    [[ $BASH_SOURCE == */* ]] && compfile="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/completions";
    compfile+="/${1##*/}";
    [[ -f "$compfile" ]] && . "$compfile" &> /dev/null && return 124;
    complete -F _minimal "$1" && return 124
}
```

Comment: Works for me. `rpm -qf /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/perl` ␤ 
`bash-completion-2.7-2.1.noarch`

Comment: What's the output of `complete -p perl`?

Comment: @EmilyE.: `bash: complete: perl: no completion specification`

Comment: Then the output of `complete -D -p`?

Comment: @EmilyE.: `complete -F _completion_loader -D`

Comment: Switching the order of `-Ilib` and `-d` works.

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is somewhere in the output of `type _perl`. Run that to have a look.

Comment: @KjetilS.: Yes I know that, but it do not work if there `-d` option alone.

Comment: @KjetilS.: `bash: type: _perl: not found`

Comment: Then you need to take a look at what `_completion_loader()` is doing.

Comment: @EmilyE.: Where to look?

Comment: No idea where it's defined on your system but you can `type _completion_loader` to see its definition.

Comment: @EmilyE.: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04. I just tried on Ubuntu 17.10, there the completion works flawlessly for `perl -d te`<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

So the easiest solution would be to update your system. If you can't (or don't want to) do that, you could try to get a newer package for your system. For Uubuntu, you could try the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~mail6543210/+archive/ubuntu/backports. Or you could get the upstream sources from http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ and completely deactive the bash-completion provided by your distribution.

Comment: This back [port](sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mail6543210/backports) does not support my system. `This PPA does not support xenial`. I have `Linux Mint 18.3`